# Do workflow instances resume after server/service restarts?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow

SharePoint 2013 Farm / 2010 Workflows

I am wondering if running SP workflows resume after a server (or necessary services) restart? For example there is a workflow-action "pause until date" available. Let´s say your workflow should pause for 3 Weeks. What if there where some server/service restarts issues in the meantime. Will that workflow run anyway? I just want to know how reliable this feature is. Didn´t find the answer yet. Thanks.

regards
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will. When an item is paused like that, the information is serialized to the database and will get picked up by the workflow timer job when the time comes to wake up and do something.

This has been the behavior ever since I can recall.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! That is the point of workflows, they are not like you think with services where they have to stop whenever a server restarts, but it is processed in **batches and states**. For example, the action "Pause until date" the workflow will really resume whenever the date passes, even if it is 10 minutes afterwards.